Preact with htm - issue while rendering
I was checking preact with htm and when try to do a simple toggle the rendering is not working properly,
My code
html
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2",
        "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/",
        "htm/preact": "https://esm.sh/htm@3.1.1/preact?external=preact"
      }
    }
</script>

<link href="~/styles/product-recommendation-new.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="product-recommendation-new-flow" class="container-fluid">

</div>

<script type="module" src="~/scripts/product-recommendation.js"></script>

JavaScript
const Toggler = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
    console.log(toggle);
    return html`<div> <h1>Count: ${toggle ? 'true' : 'false'}</h1> <button onClick=${e=>setToggle(!toggle)}>toggle</button> </div> `;
};
render(html`<${Toggler} />`, document.getElementById('product-recommendation-new-flow'));

the output i am getting on init

once I click on button


I can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-geeqow?file=index.html

Not able to reproduce in stack blitz as @rschristain said, I was able to fix this by adding a key to the element which the content is replaced. I dont know why it caused an issue in my machine.
    return html`<div> <h1 key=${toggle}>Count: ${toggle ? 'true' : 'false'}</h1> <button onClick=${e=>setToggle(!toggle)}>toggle</button> </div> `;

